# How can I save the headers and values in Html <script> as a table in the csv file?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, text-processing

I'm new to writing code. Using slenium and beautifulsoup, I managed to reach the script I want among dozens of scripts on the web page. I am looking for script [17]. When these codes are executed, the script [17] gives a result as follows.

the last part of my codes

```
html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
scripts=soup.find_all("script")
x=scripts[17]
print(x)
```

result, output
note: The list of dates is ahead of the script [17]. slide the bar. Dummy Data

Dummy Data

```
<script language="JavaScript"> var theHlp='/yardim/matris.asp';var theTitle = 'Piyasa Değeri';var theCaption='Cam (TL)';var lastmod = '';var h='<a class=hisselink href=../Hisse/HisseAnaliz.aspx?HNO=';var e='<a class=hisselink href=../endeks/endeksAnaliz.aspx?HNO=';var d='<center><font face=symbol size=1 color=#FF0000><b>ß</b></font></center>';var u='<center><font face=symbol size=1 color=#008000><b>İ</b></font></center>';var n='<center><font face=symbol size=1 color=#00A000><b>=</b></font></center>';var fr='<font color=#FF0000>';var fg='<font color=#008000>';var theFooter=new Array();var theCols = new Array();theCols[0] = new Array('Hisse',4,50);theCols[1] = new Array('2012.12',1,60);theCols[2] = new Array('2013.03',1,60);theCols[3] = new Array('2013.06',1,60);theCols[4] = new Array('2013.09',1,60);theCols[5] = new Array('2013.12',1,60);theCols[6] = new Array('2014.03',1,60);theCols[7] = new Array('2014.06',1,60);theCols[8] = new Array('2014.09',1,60);theCols[9] = new Array('2014.12',1,60);theCols[10] = new Array('2015.03',1,60);theCols[11] = new Array('2015.06',1,60);theCols[12] = new Array('2015.09',1,60);theCols[13] = new Array('2015.12',1,60);theCols[14] = new Array('2016.03',1,60);theCols[15] = new Array('2016.06',1,60);theCols[16] = new Array('2016.09',1,60);theCols[17] = new Array('2016.12',1,60);theCols[18] = new Array('2017.03',1,60);theCols[19] = new Array('2017.06',1,60);theCols[20] = new Array('2017.09',1,60);theCols[21] = new Array('2017.12',1,60);theCols[22] = new Array('2018.03',1,60);theCols[23] = new Array('2018.06',1,60);theCols[24] = new Array('2018.09',1,60);theCols[25] = new Array('2018.12',1,60);theCols[26] = new Array('2019.03',1,60);theCols[27] = new Array('2019.06',1,60);theCols[28] = new Array('2019.09',1,60);theCols[29] = new Array('2019.12',1,60);theCols[30] = new Array('2020.03',1,60);var theRows = new Array();
theRows[0] = new Array ('<b>'+h+'30>ANA</B></a>','1,114,919,783.60','1,142,792,778.19','1,091,028,645.38','991,850,000.48','796,800,000.38','697,200,000.34','751,150,000.36','723,720,000.33','888,000,000.40','790,320,000.36','883,560,000.40','927,960,000.42','737,040,000.33','879,120,000.40','914,640,000.41','927,960,000.42','1,172,160,000.53','1,416,360,000.64','1,589,520,000.72','1,552,500,000.41','1,972,500,000.53','2,520,000,000.67','2,160,000,000.58','2,475,000,000.66','2,010,000,000.54','2,250,000,000.60','2,077,500,000.55','2,332,500,000.62','3,270,000,000.87','2,347,500,000.63');
theRows[1] = new Array ('<b>'+h+'89>DEN</B></a>','55,200,000.00','55,920,000.00','45,960,000.00','42,600,000.00','35,760,000.00','39,600,000.00','40,200,000.00','47,700,000.00','50,460,000.00','45,300,000.00','41,760,000.00','59,340,000.00','66,600,000.00','97,020,000.00','81,060,000.00','69,300,000.00','79,800,000.00','68,400,000.00','66,900,000.00','66,960,000.00','71,220,000.00','71,520,000.00','71,880,000.00','60,600,000.00','69,120,000.00','62,640,000.00','57,180,000.00','89,850,000.00','125,100,000.00','85,350,000.00');
theRows[2] = new Array ('<b>'+h+'269>SIS</B></a>','4,425,000,000.00','4,695,000,000.00','4,050,000,000.00','4,367,380,000.00','4,273,120,000.00','3,644,720,000.00','4,681,580,000.00','4,913,000,000.00','6,188,000,000.00','5,457,000,000.00','6,137,000,000.00','5,453,000,000.00','6,061,000,000.00','6,954,000,000.00','6,745,000,000.00','6,519,000,000.00','7,851,500,000.00','8,548,500,000.00','9,430,000,000.00','9,225,000,000.00','10,575,000,000.00','11,610,000,000.00','9,517,500,000.00','13,140,000,000.00','12,757,500,000.00','13,117,500,000.00','11,677,500,000.00','10,507,500,000.00','11,857,500,000.00','9,315,000,000.00');
theRows[3] = new Array ('<b>'+h+'297>TRK</B></a>','1,692,579,200.00','1,983,924,800.00','1,831,315,200.00','1,704,000,000.00','1,803,400,000.00','1,498,100,000.00','1,803,400,000.00','1,884,450,000.00','2,542,160,000.00','2,180,050,000.00','2,069,200,000.00','1,682,600,000.00','1,619,950,000.00','1,852,650,000.00','2,040,600,000.00','2,315,700,000.00','2,641,200,000.00','2,938,800,000.00','3,599,100,000.00','4,101,900,000.00','5,220,600,000.00','5,808,200,000.00','4,689,500,000.00','5,375,000,000.00','3,787,500,000.00','4,150,000,000.00','3,662,500,000.00','3,712,500,000.00','4,375,000,000.00','3,587,500,000.00');
var thetable=new mytable();thetable.tableWidth=650;thetable.shownum=false;thetable.controlaccess=true;thetable.visCols=new Array(true,true,true,true,true);thetable.initsort=new Array(0,-1);thetable.inittable();thetable.refreshTable();</script>
```

My purpose is to extract this output into a table and save it as a csv file. How can i extract this script as i want?

all dates should be on top, all names should be on the far right, all values should be between the two.

```
Hisse      2012.12             2013.3             2013.4 ...
ANA      1,114,919,783.60   1,142,792,778.19     1,091,028,645.38  ...
DEN      55,200,000.00      55,920,000.00        45,960,000.00  ....
.
.
.
```

Comment: The function already takes care of a list of `<script></script>` tags. Check the list of dataframes (`dfs`) to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I reached the solution with the hint you gave and I solved the problem. I'm Hermes. You are today's mythological hero. CypherX = Zeus ... God of the gods ..

Comment: Glad it solved your requirement. Stackoverflow exists as a community to help and guide one another. There are many knowledgeable, extremely helpful people here who are always keen on sharing knowledge and improve the content on the site. I hope you come across more of them and become one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The custom-function `process_scripts()` will produce what you are looking for. I am using the dummy data given below (at the end). First we check that the code does what it is expected and so we create a pandas dataframe to see the output.

> You could also open [this Colab Jupyter Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sugatoray/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/answers/Q_62111654/Q_62111654.ipynb) and run it on Cloud for free. This will allow you to not worry about any installation or setup and simply focus on examining the solution itself.

[image: Open In Colab]

### 1. Processing A Single Script

```py
## Define CSV file-output folder-path
OUTPUT_PATH = './output'
## Process scripts
dfs = process_scripts(scripts = [s], 
                        output_path = OUTPUT_PATH, 
                        save_to_csv = False, 
                        verbose = 0)

print(dfs[0].reset_index(drop=True))
```

**Output**:

```sh
  Name           2012.12  ...            2019.12           2020.03
0  ANA  1,114,919,783.60  ...   3,270,000,000.87  2,347,500,000.63
1  DEN     55,200,000.00  ...     125,100,000.00     85,350,000.00
2  SIS  4,425,000,000.00  ...  11,857,500,000.00  9,315,000,000.00
3  TRK  1,692,579,200.00  ...   4,375,000,000.00  3,587,500,000.00

[4 rows x 31 columns]
```

---

### 2. Processing All the Scripts

You can process all your scripts using the custom-define function `process_scripts()`. The code is given below.

```py
## Define CSV file-output folder-path
OUTPUT_PATH = './output'
## Process scripts
dfs = process_scripts(scripts, 
                        output_path = OUTPUT_PATH, 
                        save_to_csv = True, 
                        verbose = 0)

## To clear the output dir-contents
#!rm -f $OUTPUT_PATH/*
```

I did this on Google Colab and it worked as expected.

[image]

### 3. Making Paths in OS-agnostic Manner

Making paths for windows or unix based systems could be very different. The following shows you a method to achieve that without having to worry about which OS you will run the code. I have used the [`os` library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html) here. However, I would suggest you to look at the [`Pathlib` library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#module-pathlib) as well.

```py
# Define relative path for output-folder
OUTPUT_PATH = './output'

# Dynamically define absolute path
pwd = os.getcwd() # present-working-directory
OUTPUT_PATH = os.path.join(pwd, os.path.abspath(OUTPUT_PATH))
```

---

### 4. Code: custom function `process_scripts()`

Here we use the `regex` (regular expression) library, along with `pandas` for organizing the data in a tabular format and then writing to csv file. The `tqdm` library is used to give you a nice *progressbar* while processing multiple scripts. Please see the comments in the code to know what to do if you are running it not from a `jupyter notebook`. The `os` library is used for path manipulation and creation of output-directory.

```py
#pip install -U pandas
#pip install tqdm
import pandas as pd
import re # regex
import os
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
# Use the following line if not using a jupyter notebook
# from tqdm import tqdm

def process_scripts(scripts, 
                    output_path='./output', 
                    save_to_csv: bool=False, 
                    verbose: int=0):
    """Process all scripts and return a list of dataframes and 
    optionally write each dataframe to a CSV file.

    Parameters
    ----------
        scripts: list of scripts
        output_path (str): output-folder-path for csv files
        save_to_csv (bool):  default is False
        verbose (int): prints output for verbose>0

    Example
    -------
    OUTPUT_PATH = './output'
    dfs = process_scripts(scripts, 
                          output_path = OUTPUT_PATH, 
                          save_to_csv = True, 
                          verbose = 0)

    ## To clear the output dir-contents
    #!rm -f $OUTPUT_PATH/*
    """
    ## Define regex patterns and compile for speed
    pat_header = re.compile(r"theCols\[\d+\] = new Array\s*\([\'](\d{4}\.\d{1,2})[\'],\d+,\d+\)")
    pat_line = re.compile(r"theRows\[\d+\] = new Array\s*\((.*)\).*")
    pat_code = re.compile("([A-Z]{3})")

    # Calculate zfill-digits
    zfill_digits = len(str(len(scripts)))
    print(f'Total scripts: {len(scripts)}')

    # Create output_path
    if not os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.makedirs(output_path)

    # Define a list of dataframes:  
    #   An accumulator of all scripts
    dfs = []

    ## If you do not have tqdm installed, uncomment the 
    #  next line and comment out the following line.
    #for script_num, script in enumerate(scripts):
    for script_num, script in enumerate(tqdm(scripts, desc='Scripts Processed')):
        ## Extract: Headers, Rows
        #    Rows : code (Name: single column), line-data (multi-column)
        headers = script.strip().split('\n', 0)[0]
        headers = ['Name'] + re.findall(pat_header, headers)
        lines = re.findall(pat_line, script)
        codes = [re.findall(pat_code, line)[0] for line in lines]
        # Clean data for each row
        lines_data = dict()
        for line, code in zip(lines, codes):
            line_data = line.replace("','", "|").split('|')
            line_data[-1] = line_data[-1].replace("'", "")
            line_data[0] = code
            lines_data.update({code: line_data.copy()})
        if verbose>0:
            print('{}: {}'.format(script_num, codes))
        ## Load data into a pandas-dataframe
        #  and write to csv.
        df = pd.DataFrame(lines_data).T
        df.columns = headers
        dfs.append(df.copy()) # update list
        # Write to CSV
        if save_to_csv:
            num_label = str(script_num).zfill(zfill_digits)
            script_file_csv = f'Script_{num_label}.csv' 
            script_path = os.path.join(output_path, script_file_csv)   
            df.to_csv(script_path, index=False)
    return dfs
```

---

### 5. Dummy Data

```py
## Dummy Data
s = """
<script language="JavaScript"> var theHlp='/yardim/matris.asp';var theTitle = 'Piyasa Değeri';var theCaption='Cam (TL)';var lastmod = '';var h='<a class=hisselink href=../Hisse/HisseAnaliz.aspx?HNO=';var e='<a class=hisselink href=../endeks/endeksAnaliz.aspx?HNO=';var d='<center><font face=symbol size=1 color=#FF0000><b>ß</b></font></center>';var u='<center><font face=symbol size=1 color=#008000><b>İ</b></font></center>';var n='<center><font face=symbol size=1 color=#00A000><b>=</b></font></center>';var fr='<font color=#FF0000>';var fg='<font color=#008000>';var theFooter=new Array();var theCols = new Array();theCols[0] = new Array('Hisse',4,50);theCols[1] = new Array('2012.12',1,60);theCols[2] = new Array('2013.03',1,60);theCols[3] = new Array('2013.06',1,60);theCols[4] = new Array('2013.09',1,60);theCols[5] = new Array('2013.12',1,60);theCols[6] = new Array('2014.03',1,60);theCols[7] = new Array('2014.06',1,60);theCols[8] = new Array('2014.09',1,60);theCols[9] = new Array('2014.12',1,60);theCols[10] = new Array('2015.03',1,60);theCols[11] = new Array('2015.06',1,60);theCols[12] = new Array('2015.09',1,60);theCols[13] = new Array('2015.12',1,60);theCols[14] = new Array('2016.03',1,60);theCols[15] = new Array('2016.06',1,60);theCols[16] = new Array('2016.09',1,60);theCols[17] = new Array('2016.12',1,60);theCols[18] = new Array('2017.03',1,60);theCols[19] = new Array('2017.06',1,60);theCols[20] = new Array('2017.09',1,60);theCols[21] = new Array('2017.12',1,60);theCols[22] = new Array('2018.03',1,60);theCols[23] = new Array('2018.06',1,60);theCols[24] = new Array('2018.09',1,60);theCols[25] = new Array('2018.12',1,60);theCols[26] = new Array('2019.03',1,60);theCols[27] = new Array('2019.06',1,60);theCols[28] = new Array('2019.09',1,60);theCols[29] = new Array('2019.12',1,60);theCols[30] = new Array('2020.03',1,60);var theRows = new Array();
theRows[0] = new Array ('<b>'+h+'30>ANA</B></a>','1,114,919,783.60','1,142,792,778.19','1,091,028,645.38','991,850,000.48','796,800,000.38','697,200,000.34','751,150,000.36','723,720,000.33','888,000,000.40','790,320,000.36','883,560,000.40','927,960,000.42','737,040,000.33','879,120,000.40','914,640,000.41','927,960,000.42','1,172,160,000.53','1,416,360,000.64','1,589,520,000.72','1,552,500,000.41','1,972,500,000.53','2,520,000,000.67','2,160,000,000.58','2,475,000,000.66','2,010,000,000.54','2,250,000,000.60','2,077,500,000.55','2,332,500,000.62','3,270,000,000.87','2,347,500,000.63');
theRows[1] = new Array ('<b>'+h+'89>DEN</B></a>','55,200,000.00','55,920,000.00','45,960,000.00','42,600,000.00','35,760,000.00','39,600,000.00','40,200,000.00','47,700,000.00','50,460,000.00','45,300,000.00','41,760,000.00','59,340,000.00','66,600,000.00','97,020,000.00','81,060,000.00','69,300,000.00','79,800,000.00','68,400,000.00','66,900,000.00','66,960,000.00','71,220,000.00','71,520,000.00','71,880,000.00','60,600,000.00','69,120,000.00','62,640,000.00','57,180,000.00','89,850,000.00','125,100,000.00','85,350,000.00');
theRows[2] = new Array ('<b>'+h+'269>SIS</B></a>','4,425,000,000.00','4,695,000,000.00','4,050,000,000.00','4,367,380,000.00','4,273,120,000.00','3,644,720,000.00','4,681,580,000.00','4,913,000,000.00','6,188,000,000.00','5,457,000,000.00','6,137,000,000.00','5,453,000,000.00','6,061,000,000.00','6,954,000,000.00','6,745,000,000.00','6,519,000,000.00','7,851,500,000.00','8,548,500,000.00','9,430,000,000.00','9,225,000,000.00','10,575,000,000.00','11,610,000,000.00','9,517,500,000.00','13,140,000,000.00','12,757,500,000.00','13,117,500,000.00','11,677,500,000.00','10,507,500,000.00','11,857,500,000.00','9,315,000,000.00');
theRows[3] = new Array ('<b>'+h+'297>TRK</B></a>','1,692,579,200.00','1,983,924,800.00','1,831,315,200.00','1,704,000,000.00','1,803,400,000.00','1,498,100,000.00','1,803,400,000.00','1,884,450,000.00','2,542,160,000.00','2,180,050,000.00','2,069,200,000.00','1,682,600,000.00','1,619,950,000.00','1,852,650,000.00','2,040,600,000.00','2,315,700,000.00','2,641,200,000.00','2,938,800,000.00','3,599,100,000.00','4,101,900,000.00','5,220,600,000.00','5,808,200,000.00','4,689,500,000.00','5,375,000,000.00','3,787,500,000.00','4,150,000,000.00','3,662,500,000.00','3,712,500,000.00','4,375,000,000.00','3,587,500,000.00');
var thetable=new mytable();thetable.tableWidth=650;thetable.shownum=false;thetable.controlaccess=true;thetable.visCols=new Array(true,true,true,true,true);thetable.initsort=new Array(0,-1);thetable.inittable();thetable.refreshTable();</script>
"""

## Make a dummy list of scripts
scripts = [s for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215267/discussion-on-answer-by-cypherx-how-can-i-save-the-headers-and-values-in-html-s).

Answer (score 0):

According to the provided `<script>` in your question, you can do something like code below to have a list of Dates for each name `ANA, DEN ..`:

```
for _ in range(1, len(aaa.split("<b>'"))-1):
  s = aaa.split("<b>'")[_].split("'")
  print(_)
  lst = []
  for i in s:
    if "</B>" in i:
      name = i.split('>')[1].split("<")[0]
      print("{} = ".format(name), end="")
    if any(j.isdigit() for j in i) and ',' in i:
      lst.append(i)
  print(lst)
```

It's just an example code, so it's not that beautiful :)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I do not have enough information. I'm a complete beginner. :(

Comment: for _ in range(1, len(x.split("<b>'"))-1):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable :(

Comment: I edited the answer, you can just replace `x` with `aaa` and it should work.

Comment: ben o değeri değiştirmiştim ama sonuç hata verdi. 
The result gave the same error :( for _ in range(1, len(aaa.split("<b>'"))-1):
NameError: name 'aaa' is not defined

Comment: You should replace this code with the last line in your code `print(aaa)`. the error `NameError: name 'aaa' is not defined` saying that there's no variable named `aaa` before.\

Comment: The list of dates is ahead of the script [17]. slide the bar.

Comment: new Array('2012.12',1,60);theCols[2] = new Array('2013.03',1,60);theCols[3] = new Array('2013.06',1,60);theCols[4] = new Array('2013.09',1,60);theCols[5] = new Array('2013.12',1,60);theCols[6] = new Array('2014.03',1,60);theCols[7] = new Array('2014.06',1,60);theCols[8] = new Array('2014.09',1,60);theCols[9] = new Array('2014.12',1,60);theCols[10] = new Array('2015.03',1,60);theCols[11] = new Array('2015.06',1,60);theCols[12] = new Array('2015.09',1,60);theCols[13] = new Array('2015.12',1,60);theCols[14] = new Array('2016.03',1,60);theCols[15] = new

Comment: The list of dates is available as data in the script [17] output. Scroll the bar.